# GETDATE() always returns 12:00:00 AM

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

In my ASP.NET (C#) project, I'm inserting some data into a database.

```
INSERT INTO USERS (username,join_date) VALUES('Ali',GETDATE());
```

Now when I'm fetching the date from the database, I'm using **DateTime**.

```
SqlDataReader r = Command.ExecuteReader();
r.Read();
myDate = r.getDateTime(0);
```

And when I'm inserting this in some DIV, I do this.

```
"<div>"+myDate.ToLongTimeString()+"</div>"
```

I get the correct date as in **day/month/year**, but the hour is always **12:00:00 AM**.

How can I get the exact time?

Comment: What is the type of `join_date` column?

Comment: join_date 's type is DATE, SQL SERVER 2008

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `DATE` as your column type means you are only storing the date not the time.

Therefore when you read the value back into a `DateTime` object the system has to initialise the time part - to midnight.

Convert the column to `DATETIME` and you'll get the time component stored as well.

For more information on the difference see the MSDN page on [Date and Time Data Types and Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx)

Answer (score 7):

make sure join_date is of type DATETIME and not DATE in the database

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx

Comment: @canolucas - the OP does know how the site works. There is a delay built into the system so you have to wait for a while before you can accept an answer.

Comment: @canolucas I was actually thinking for whom I should give the "Best Answer", since you and ChrisF gave me correct answers.

I was more about to give ChrisF the best answer because he explained more, but then I saw that your new, and I thought about giving it to you as a motivation, but since you just proved that you helped for the sake of points, not for the sake of helping and learning and educating, then ChrisF really deserves it.

Comment: @ali Bassam no problem, i also think he deserves it because his answer has more details. i just want you to know that i was not helping you just for the sake of points because that are not my intentions :) best wishes